# Does IRC §871(i) (no tax on deposit interest for non-residents) apply to interest paid by the IRS on delayed refunds?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, non-resident

[Internal Revenue Code §871(i)(3)](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/details/USCODE-2019-title26/USCODE-2019-title26-subtitleA-chap1-subchapN-partII-subpartA-sec871&collectionCode=USCODE) basically says that "deposit interest" on a deposit in a **US bank** is not taxable for US non-resident aliens.

The IRS [pays interest on delayed refunds](https://www.irs.gov/newsroom/13-point-9-million-americans-to-receive-irs-tax-refund-interest-taxable-payments-to-average-18-dollars) and issues a 1099-INT, which would normally be taxable income for a US tax resident.

Is this interest taxable income for a **US tax non-resident** or is it considered non-taxable under §871(i)(3) similar to most other interest income reported on a 1099-INT.

EDIT: My understanding is that if a NRA received the refund on time and put it in a bank account, the interest would not be taxable. Hence, the "spirit of the law" should allow the same for interest payed by the IRS for a delayed refund, but I don't see this clearly mentioned anywhere.